# What ports does MS SQL Server use for ODBC connections?

Tags: odbc, ms-sql

I require our firewall to allow ODBC connection from clients to the MS SQL Server.

Which ports should be opened for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We opened these ports and that did the trick. We can ping the server and create an odbc connection to the server:

```
1433 (ODBC)
icmp 
netbios (UDP ports 137, 138 & TCP 139 for NetBIOS over TCP)
```

Answer (score 4):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175483.aspx):

```
Default instances of the Database Engine use TCP port 1433 by default.
```

Answer (score -1):

Server: "IPAddress\NameofService,Port"

You need to use comma, after name of service, example: "localhost\MSSQLSERVER,1433"

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.